# MASM32 (assembly) accessing element of 1D array using 2D coordinates

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm making a snake game in assembly and I am storing the coordinates of the body of the snake (for collision purpose) in a 1 dimensional array. I am storing the x and y coordinates in a byte. I am storing the coordinates of the head of the snake every time it moves. Here is my code:

```
;(ROW * WIDTH) + COL
MOV AL, 80 ; 80 IS THE WIDTH
MUL ROW
ADD AL, COL
MOV SI, AX
CMP TRAIL[SI], 0
JE @GAME_OVER
```

I made a 1 dimensional array named TRAIL to hold the data.

```
TRAIL DB 2000 dup (1)
```

My problem is that sometimes, the snake dies even though it did not collide with the body. I think the problem is when multiplying ROW to AL (sometimes larger than AL) then adding COL gives the wrong answer. I cannot change ROW and COL to dw so my only choice is to make that computation work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing a byte addition you can operate on words:

```
mov ax,80
mul byte [ROW]
movzx bx,byte [COL]  ; zero-extend COL into BX
add ax,bx            ; ax = ROW*80 + COL
```

Or if you don't want to use `movzx`:

```
mov ax,80
mul byte [ROW]
add al,[COL]
adc ah,0       ; add 1 to AH if the previous addition resulted in a carry
```

The `ADC` (Add with Carry) is more or less logically equivalent to the following C statement:

```
    ah += (((uint16_t)al + col) > 0xFF) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I am getting an error which says "Type illegal in context" in these lines:
mul byte [ROW]
movzx bx,byte [COL]  ; zero-extend COL into BX

Comment: My code was in NASM syntax. For MASM/TASM you'd write `byte ptr` instead of `byte`.

Comment: It works now. Thank you. Could you explain what "mul byte [row]", "add al,[col]", and "adc ah,0 " do?

Comment: `mul byte [row]` is really no different than `mul row`. I just stated explicitly that the operand is a byte; but the assembler would've figured that out by itself. `add al,[col]` means the same things as `add al,col` in TASM/MASM syntax, but NASM requires brackets around the variable name. The purpose of the `adc` is explained in the comment; it's essentially taking the ninth bit of the result from the previous addition and adding it to `AH` (the high byte of `AX`).